# ggplot2 issue with y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have the following means table:

```
   Sex Trait   Average
1    1    -N  9.042735
2    2    -N  3.529577
3    1     E  8.111111
4    2     E  9.447887
5    1     O 17.196580
6    2     O 16.311800
7    1     A 12.213680
8    2     A 13.449440
9    1     C 12.025640
10   2     C 14.529580
```

From where I run the following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(meansMatrix, aes(Trait, Average, colour= Sex,group= Sex)) +
      geom_line(aes(linetype=Sex),size=1) + 
      geom_point(size=3,fill="white") + 
      scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey50")) +
      scale_y_discrete(limits=c(0,18),breaks=seq(2,18,2.5),labels=seq(2,18,2.5)) +
      scale_x_discrete(limits=c("-N","E","O","A","C")); plot
```

[image]
There is visible a problem with the y axis. After setting the variable `Average` as numeric,  I have tried with different combinations by changing the arguments (`limits, breaks` and `labels`) with no success. This is graph is the only that pops up else than error messages.

Any input of how to re-locate the plot and show the corresponding breaks will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scale_y_continuous`:

```
meansMatrix <- read.table(text="   Sex Trait   Average
1    1    -N  9.042735
2    2    -N  3.529577
3    1     E  8.111111
4    2     E  9.447887
5    1     O 17.196580
6    2     O 16.311800
7    1     A 12.213680
8    2     A 13.449440
9    1     C 12.025640
10   2     C 14.529580", header=TRUE)

meansMatrix$Sex <- factor(meansMatrix$Sex)


library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(meansMatrix, aes(Trait, Average, colour= Sex,group= Sex)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Sex),size=1) + 
  geom_point(size=3,fill="white") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey50")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,18),breaks=seq(2,18,2.5),labels=seq(2,18,2.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("-N","E","O","A","C")) 

print(p)
```

[image]